# Creating word pairs, triplets etc for evaluation in Bleu

Tags: java, string

I need to create a list of word pairs, triplets etc for evaluation in the Bleu metric. Bleu starts with unigrams (a single word) and goes up to N-grams - the N being specified at runtime.

For example, given the sentence 
"Israeli officials are responsible for airport security"

For unigrams it would just be a list of the words. For bigrams it would be

```
Israeli officials
officials are
are responsible
responsible for
for airport
airport security
```

The relevant trigrams are

```
Israeli officials are
officials are responsible
are responsible for
responsible for aiport
for airport security
```

I've coded a working Bleu that hard codes the NGrams to 4 and brute forces the calculations of the unigrams etc. It's ugly as hell, and besides, I need to be able to supply the N at run time.

The snippet that's trying to generate the pairs / triplets etc -

```
    String current = "";
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < goldWords.length - N_GRAM_ORDER; i++) {
        current = current + ":" + goldWords[i];
        while (temp < N_GRAM_ORDER) {
            current = current + ":" + goldWords[temp + i];
            temp++;
        }
        goldNGrams.add(current);
        current = "";
        temp = 0;
    }
}
```

Edit - so the output from this snippet should be for bigrams -

```
israeli:officials
officials:are
are:responsible
responsible:for
for:airport
airport:security
```

Where goldWords is a String array containing the individual words to be made into NGrams.
I've been tinkering with this loop for days, drawing out the relationships etc and it just won't click for me. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are just breaking out a string of words by how many spaces there are, correct?  Couldn't you do this: use String.split to split the input string into an array of words, then use a loop to recombine them into N pieces.  Throw in a command line argument to determine N, and you are set

Comment: you're adding `goldWords[i]` to the `current` string twice. Once when you initialize `current`, then again with the first iteration of the while loop.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus the string array goldWords is the original sentence, split into individual words. The problem is combining them properly.

Comment: @deanosaur it's there twice because for say, for unigrams, the first word will be israeli. Then it needs to add the second, officials. It adds that bigram to the arraylist as israeli:officals. Then it needs to jump back and take the word officials, and combine it with are, and add officals:are to the array list of bigrams

Comment: but this code will create a bigram `israeli:israeli:officials`, which is 1) not a bigram and 2) wrong.

Comment: Sorry I should have pointed out, for unigrams, order = 0, bigrams, order = 1 etc. So for unigrams (N = 0) it should skip the while loop etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this:

```
String current = "";
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < goldWords.length - N_GRAM_ORDER; i++) {
    current = current + ":" + goldWords[i];
    while (temp < N_GRAM_ORDER) {
        current = current + ":" + goldWords[temp + i];
        temp++;
    }
    goldNGrams.add(current);
    current = "";
    temp = 0;
}
}
```

to this:

```
 String current = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < goldWords.length(); i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < N_GRAM_ORDER; j++){
            if (i + j < goldWords.length())
                 current += ":" + goldWords[i + j];
     }
     goldNGrams.add(current);
     current = "";
 }
```

So, the outer for loop iterates through the first word to be included, the inner loop iterates through all the words to be included.  One thing to note is that the if statement is used to prevent an array out of bounds error.  This should be moved to outside the inner for loop if you only want complete n-grams.

With the if statement where it is you will get:

```
Israeli:officials
officials:are
are:responsible
responsible:for
for:airport
airport:security
security
```

If you want:

```
Israeli:officials
officials:are
are:responsible
responsible:for
for:airport
airport:security
```

instead, try this code:

```
 String current = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < goldWords.length(); i++){
     if (i + N_GRAM_ORDER < goldWords.length()){
         for (int j = 0; j < N_GRAM_ORDER; j++){
                 current += ":" + goldWords[i + j];
         }
     }
     goldNGrams.add(current);
     current = "";
 }
```

(the above code is done without checking it against the compiler, so there might be an Off By One or minor syntax error in it.  Validate it, but it will get you close).

Comment: Thank you, the first snippet you posted does exactly what I need, it just needed to be slightly updated to get the last entry - changing if (i + j < goldWords.length) to if (i + j <= goldWords.length)

Comment: Downside to not having the compiler handy, I couldn't test it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that uses a String[] to collect the ngrams instead of a string. I changed the number of iterations on the outer for loop to ensure it captures the last n-gram.

```
public static List<String[]> ngrams(String[] gold, int n_length) {
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < gold.length - (n_length-1); i++) {
        String[] ngram = new String[n_length];
        for(int j = 0; j < n_length; j++) {
            ngram[j] = gold[i+j];
        }
        list.add(ngram);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: If I could mark this as an answer also I would, it also does what I need in a different way - thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

according to the N_GRAM programming output

```
  int N_GRAM_ORDER = 3, temp = 0, i;
        for (i = 0; i <= goldWords.length - N_GRAM_ORDER; i += N_GRAM_ORDER) {
            while (temp < N_GRAM_ORDER) {
                current = current + ":" + goldWords[temp + i];
                temp++;

            }
            goldGrams.add(current);
            current = "";
            temp = 0;
        }

        if ((temp + i) < goldWords.length) {
            temp += i;
            while (temp < goldWords.length) {

                current = current + ":" + goldWords[temp++];

            }
            goldGrams.add(current);

        }

    }
```

**output**

```
Israeli:officials:are
responsible:for:airport
security
```